# How do I find the element number with an id in jquery?

Tags: jquery

```
<ul>
 <li><div id="some1">.....</div></li>
 <li><div id="some22">.....</div></li>
 <li><div id="somed">.....</div></li>
 <li><div id="some54">.....</div></li>
 <li><div id="some77">.....</div></li>
 <li><div id="some32">.....</div></li>
 <li><div id="some2">.....</div></li>
</ul>
```

In the above structure, I want to find the number or index+1 of the `li` whose child is #somed. so basically for `#somed` I want to get a value of 3. Any ideas how to do this in jquery?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('#somed').closest('li').index()+1;
```

[**Here is a demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Shef/vxfwG/)

Answer (score 0):

This answer posted as a more generalised solution, that should work for all `li` elements with a child `div` with an `id` starting with 'some':

```
$('div[id^="some"]').click(
    function(){
        var indexOfParent = $(this).closest('li').index();
        alert(indexOfParent); // alerts '2', due to zero-based JavaScript arrays.
    });
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/wmnG7/1/).

If you *need* it to be `3`, rather than the native JavaScript index (zero-based), then you'll have to explicitly add `1` to the variable.

Answer (score 0):

Try

`$('#someId').parent().index()+1`

Since your elements are wrapped, you'll need to test off of the list elements containing your divs. You might consider putting the ids on the `li`s and figuring out if you *really* need divs at all, but that's another discussion.

[jQuery index() method](http://api.jquery.com/index/)